# Xamarin - Mono and Android communication

Tags: android, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

I was going through Xamarin documentation https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/architecture/ and it says

> "Xamarin.Android applications run within the Mono execution environment. This execution environment runs side-by-side with the
>   Android Runtime (ART) virtual machine. Both runtime environments run
>   on top of the Linux kernel and expose various APIs to the user code
>   that allows developers to access the underlying system"

As far as I understand, an app is a single process - what does it mean to say that there are two execution environments? Is it like these two environments are started in different threads in the same process? Or is it like Android Runtime boots up and then start Mono runtime?

Answer (score 4):

You just had to read further to [Application Startup](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/architecture/#Application_Startup). The Runtime is loaded during the creation of the process:

> Xamarin.Android hooks into this by adding a mono.MonoRuntimeProvider ContentProvider to AndroidManifest.xml during the build process. The mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo() method is responsible for loading the Mono runtime into the process. Any attempts to use Mono prior to this point will fail. ( Note: This is why types which subclass Android.App.Application need to provide an (IntPtr, JniHandleOwnership) constructor, as the Application instance is created before Mono can be initialized.)

The mentioned part of the `AndroidManifest.xml` looks like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="foo.sample" android:installLocation="auto" 
          android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <application ...>

    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" 
              android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" 
              android:authorities="foo.sample.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />

  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I can only upvote this. This doesn't explain my actual question - "As far as I understand, an app is a single process - what does it mean to say that there are two execution environments?"